# Unstable Wifi on Thinkpad X250, Ubuntu 14.04, Intel Corp. Wireless 7265

Tags: 14.04, networking, thinkpad

I have an unstable connection using this wireless chip. It does not seem to have internet randomly from 2-10 minutes beyond which I have to restart the network to get a working internet connection. It still says connnected to wifi though. Another thing I have noticed is that it works very well from some places, but other places where other X250s work, this does not.

Comment: I think that [my problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722239/wifi-doesnt-work) is the same. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely the driver. It seems it has some issues with keeping a solid connection to wifi  (802.11)

You can check if this solution will help it will reset after a reboot.

Reload the iwlwifi kernel module with option 11n_disable set to 1, in order to disable 802.11N, e.g. by

```
sudo sh -c 'modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1'
```

If this helped your connection you can make it last permanently disabling 802.11N in the driver, add the line

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

to

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

or issue the following bash command, that does the above automatically. You will be asked for your sudo password as we are modifying a system file.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade the kernel to the latest lts version and disable the power management to get it stable. The steps are below:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid linux-image-generic-lts-vivid linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic
```

Then create a file in

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireles
```

and copy and paste the code below:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/power.d/wireles
```

and reboot with the new kernel. I hope it helps.